# Running a code in background thread in android

Tags: java, android, background-thread

I am new to the development of Android applications. I came across a situation where i need to execute a code in a background thread that does not do something with the UI. Based on the result obtained from the background thread I need to display an alert message on the UI. I heard about AsyncTask class which can be used to execute code in background process but in Android documentation i found that it was deprecated from API Level R.

Can you please suggest on how a particular block of code can be executed in background thread? and also based on the result display the alert on the main UI.

Comment: Google recommends that you use the concurrency framework that java already has.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask

Comment: https://github.com/crawlinknetworks/android-promise

This is excellent Library, similar to Prowerful Javascript Promises to execute async work.

Comment: since you are starting on Android , it would be easier for you to use a normal thread class to perform your operation in background and a Handler class to post it back to the UI thread

Comment: @libanbn It says that AsyncTask was deprecated..

Comment: @Kamal Yes, and on that site they also said to use the default concurrency classes in java. Here are some examples on how to use them: https://winterbe.com/posts/2015/04/07/java8-concurrency-tutorial-thread-executor-examples/

Comment: @libanbn is it the threads and runnables? Or executor services ?that needs to used for my purpose What is the best solution? Please suggest

Comment: @p.mathew13 Can you Please suggest an example on how it can be implemented? Any links that needs to be referred will be much more helpful

Comment: @Kamal The tread and runnable should work fine. If you want to display something based on the result of the async thread, you can use callbacks to your UI thread.

Comment: @Kamal This can be a good place for you to start https://medium.com/@ankit.sinhal/handler-in-android-d138c1f4980e